# get meta value from page query

Tags: post-meta

I need to check each page to see if it has a default template or another template assigned. If it's default, I want to do X if it's not, then I will do Y. Problem I found is that the query is not showing that particular field. I wanted to find

```
 [meta_key] => '_wp_page_template',
 [meta_value] => 'default'
```

that is what I was testing for but it doesn't seem to be working. I did some looking here and found this code

```
 function get_meta_values( $key = '', $type = 'page', $status = 'publish' ) {
global $wpdb;
if( empty( $key ) )
    return;
$r = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
    SELECT DISTINCT pm.meta_value FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} pm
    LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} p ON p.ID = pm.post_id
    WHERE pm.meta_key = '%s' 
    AND p.post_status = '%s' 
    AND p.post_type = '%s'
", $key, $status, $type ) );
return $r;
}
```

so then in my custom query using WP_Query, I check like so

```
 $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
        );

        $page_query = new WP_Query( $args );

        if ( $page_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $page_query->have_posts() ) : $page_query->the_post(); ?>
        <?php $template = get_meta_values('_wp_page_template');
        if( $template != 'default'){ ?>
 //run X here
  }
 else {
 //run Y here
  }
 the rest of the loop follows below.
```

Some of the pages should run X and some should run Y but they all seem to be running X.

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong? When I do a var_dump of $page_query, I do not see the [meta_key] field in the array. That's why I thought the get_meta_values function would solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are in your `while` loop, the parent query is already finished. So fetch the post meta value with `get_post_meta()`:

```
$template = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_wp_page_template', TRUE );
```

Comment: Thank you both for your response. Toscho, it worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you could try out `get_page_template()` ([#](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_template)).

Here is an example, that prints out all the pages and the corresponding page template:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);
$page_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $page_query->have_posts() ){
    while ( $page_query->have_posts() ) : $page_query->the_post(); 
        printf("<strong>%s</strong> has template <strong>%s</strong> <br/>", get_the_title(), basename(get_page_template()));
    endwhile;
}
?>
```

This will give you a list like this one:

```
About has template page.php 
Staff has template page.php 
Products has template tpl_products.php 
...
```